# MySQL JOIN with blank/null values returns no results

Tags: mysql, join, null

I'm trying to return some values optionally (if they exist) and if not return the rest of the set.

```
SELECT people.first_name, countries1.name AS "Country1" 
FROM addressbook_people AS people
JOIN root_countries AS countries1 ON people.country1 = countries1.id
```

On some cases there will be no value supplied for people.country1,
however if one it not supplied no results.

How would I restructure this query to still return people.first_name 
when there is no value in people.country1?

Comment: maybe change the `JOIN` to `LEFT JOIN`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Just do

```
SELECT people.first_name, countries1.name AS "Country1" 
FROM addressbook_people AS people
LEFT JOIN root_countries AS countries1 ON people.country1 = countries1.id
```

which will result to returning `NULL` on the respective fields of the `root_countries` table.